# isql exception unixODBC data source name not found

Tags: php, sql-server, sqlcmd, unixodbc, isql

I am trying to connect my php application with SQL server in my Linux box.
I installed unixODBC successfully and made required changes in odbc.ini and odbcinst.ini file.

When I run command.`<br><b>sqlcmd -S DSN -U USERNAME -P Password</b>`

I am able to connect to sql server, but when I tried to connect with same DSN using isql `(isql -v DSN USERNAME PASSWORD)<br>` I am gating Data source name not found exception.

content of my odbc.ini file is

> [SPSQLDEV]
>  Driver = ODBC Driver 11 for SQL SERVER
>  server =
>   ***.com,portno
>  Database = TEST

content of odbcinst.ini is

> [SQL SERVER Native Client 11.0]
>  Driver =
>   /opt/microsoft/sqlncli/lib64/libsqlncli-11.0.so.1790.0
>  Threading =
>   1
> Output of command **odbcinst -q -d** is.
> SQL Server Native
>   Client 11.0 
> out put of command **odbcinst -q -s** is 
>   SPSQLDEV

Comment: are you sure the Database name is correct (have you tried adding the file extension)?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yes the database name is correct.

Comment: does your SQL server require username/password access? But does sound like your database isn't found/inaccessible/corrupt/etc

Comment: Yes database needs username and password. I am able to access database using sqlcmd using same DSN.

Comment: or could be smething like this missing: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11162549/3913686

Answer (score 0):

On MacOS put your odbc.ini on /usr/local/etc/odbc.ini then run your isql command